# How to attach ids from array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In vue.js i have array like this:

```
Array[4]
0:"5"
1:"7"
2:"9"
3:"72"
```

But when i do this in controller:

```
 $features[] = $request->features;
```

I get this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "5,7,9,72"
]
```

What i want is to attach those ids like this:

```
  if(!empty($features)){
              $property->features()->attach($features);
        }
```

Any suggestion how can i do that? And am i doing something wrong?

```
dd($request->features);
```

i get:

> "5,7,9,72"

I figured out. I need to use like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.property_credentials.features.length; i++) {
                data.append('features[]', this.property_credentials.features[i]);
            }
```

Comment: There is something wrong in transmission as what you get in php is not an array.
you get array with one item whose value is string.

Comment: when i do   dd($request->features); i get "5,7,9,72"

Comment: This is a string not an array.
Post the VueJS code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
Instead of `$features[] = $request->features;`,
try, `$features = $request->features;`